# React filter multiple object key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

trying to work with Minimals.cc and I have a problem with the search feature that include only the names and that I need to extends to other key of the objects I'm filtering (filterAll). Here is the code:

```
function applySortFilter({ tableData, comparator, filterName, filterCircle, filterAll }) {
  const stabilizedThis = tableData.map((el, index) => [el, index]);

  stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
    const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
    if (order !== 0) return order;
    return a[1] - b[1];
  });

  tableData = stabilizedThis.map((el) => el[0]);


 // this is the one i'm trying to make that should includes both item.name and item.circle_name

  if (filterAll) {
    tableData = tableData.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterAll.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }


  if (filterName) {
    tableData = tableData.filter((item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterName.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }

  if (filterCircle) {
    tableData = tableData.filter((item) => item.circle_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterCircle.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
  }


  return tableData;
}
```

I tried playing with && and || in the filter method to add item.circle_name and item.name but it did not work (at least for the way I did it).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you not just using `item.name.toLowerCase() === filterAll.toLowerCase()` ? What is the structure of `tableData` and the value of `filterAll`?

Comment: `tableData` is a normal array of object => `[{name: 'abc', circle_name:'blue'},{name:'def', circle_name:'red'},{name:'hij', circle_name:'green'}]`,
`filterAll` has the value of the input so `''` at first.

Answer (score 0):

After trying more the answer that would work is:

```
if (filterAll) {
    tableData = tableData.filter((item) => (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterAll.toLowerCase()) && item.circle_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterAll.toLowerCase())) !== -1);
  }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).